# sql - agrregate count and share by multiple groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

with table `t1` like below, for each `make` need to get the count and % share for each `type`

```
+--------+------+
|  make  | type |
+--------+------+
| toyota | car  |
| audi   | suv  |
| bmw    | suv  |
| bmw    | suv  |
| audi   | car  |
+--------+------+
```

The required output is as below.

```
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|  make  | type | vehicle_cnt   | vehicle_pct   |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| toyota | car  |             1 |         100.0 |
| audi   | suv  |             1 |         50.0  |
| audi   | car  |             1 |         50.0  |
| bmw    | suv  |             2 |         100.0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
```

I'm able to get the count for each type by make (as `vehicle_cnt`) using the query below. However need inputs on how to get the percentage share as well.

```
select
make
 , type
 , count (*) as vehicle_cnt
 from t1
 group by make, type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try different aggregation windows, like here:

```
select DISTINCT
make
 , type
 , count (*) over (partition by make, type) as vehicle_cnt
 , count (1) over (partition by make, type)*100 / count (1) over (partition by make) as vehicle_pct
 from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a couple of CTEs:

```
with CTE as
(
select
make
 , type
 , count (*) as vehicle_cnt
 from t1
 group by make, type
),
M2 as
(
select type, sum(vehicle_cnt) as tot
from CTE
group by type
)
select CTE.*, 100*(CTE.vehicle_cnt/M2.tot) as pc
from CTE
inner join M2
on m2.type = CTE.type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select make,
       type,
       count(*) as vehicle_cnt,
       round((count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from t1)::numeric), 1) as vehicle_pct
  from t1
 group by make, type
```